# How to filter a relation where ID in <list of ids split from a string> in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a materialised path kept in the `ancestry` field in form of: `id1/id2/id3` like: `1/29/13`

Then I want to select those which have the ids: id1, id2, id3 like it would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM departments
WHERE ID IN (1,29,427)
```

but having the (1,29,427) coming from the `ancestry` field.

Something like this:

```
-- Direct ancestors of '433' dep
SELECT ancestors.id, ancestors.ancestry, ancestors.name
FROM departments target, departments ancestors 
--WHERE ancestors.id IN (1,29)
--WHERE ancestors.id IN STRING_TO_ARRAY(target.ancestry, '/')::integer
--WHERE ancestors.id IN (unnest(STRING_TO_ARRAY(target.ancestry, '/')::INTEGER[]))
--WHERE ancestors.id IN (target.ancestry)
WHERE ancestors.id IN (STRING_TO_ARRAY(target.ancestry, '/')::INTEGER[])
AND target.id = 433
```

The above is not working the question would be how to make it working?
Thx

Comment: "I have a list of ids" mistake #1. Don't store multiple pieces of info in a single column, instead normalize it into a separate table. Then you can just use a join and/or relational division

Comment: Bad database design. You need to normalize your design at least to [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Comment: Next question will be why this query is slow... Fix your database design as soon as possible, your current model is the opposite of a relational model for a relational database like PostgreSQL.

Comment: @TheImpaler  and @Charlieface This is the `materialized path` pattern to store hierarchy of objects in a relational db. The benefit of the `materialized path` is that with one single query We can retrieve:
- ancestors
- childs
- parent
- root
- descendants
- siblings
- subtree
- path

@frank-heikens please don't try to joke what my next question will be.

I assure You guys the db design is just fine: `materialized path` that is the keyword You need to check and learn ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the query that involves joining two tables based on a `department's ID` matching any ID derived from splitting and converting a slash-separated ancestry field into an array of integers. Try this

```
SELECT ancestors.id, ancestors.ancestry, ancestors.name
FROM departments target
JOIN departments ancestors ON ancestors.id = ANY(STRING_TO_ARRAY(target.ancestry, '/')::INTEGER[])
WHERE target.id = 433;
```

Comment: Continuing with the bad database design just worsens the trouble of this database. It needs normalization, and then queries will be trivial.

Comment: @TheImpaler The design is just good for the purposes. It is called `materialized path`. It is intended to hold a hierarchy in relational dbs. With one single query we can retrieve: - ancestors - childs - parent - root - descendants - siblings - subtree - path. There is nothing wrong with this db design.

Comment: @TheImpaler If You know better design for hierarchical data then please share the keywords ;) But IMO judging like "bad design" without knowing anything about it is not conversational nor constructive.